# Is there a way to pass a list of values to df.loc method of pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to filter a data frame using values I receive from a user. The problem I'm facing is I could not find a way to use the loc method if there is more than one value for the input. Say loan amounts are 300, 400 and 600. Ideally, I'd like to pass a list of values. How can I accomplish this? See the code below to understand the filtering

```
mortgage_df = df.loc[(df['loan_purpose'] == loan_purpose) & (df['loan_amount'] == loan_amount)]
```

Comment: `df['loan_amount].isin(loan_amount)` where loan_amount variable is a list

Answer (score 0):

Sample input

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "loan_purpose": ['A', 'B', 'B', 'D'],
    'loan_amount' : [200, 300, 400, 500]
})
```

df.loc[(df.loan_purpose == 'B') & df.loan_amount.isin([300, 400])]

Result

```
loan_purpose    loan_amount
1   B   300
2   B   400
```